# how can I refer to the current object in a With block?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VBA project for a workbook that has three sheets.  I want to be able to get the last used row number for any one of them.  There will never be any blank rows between used rows on the sheets, so I can use CurrentRegion.  I would like to write a little function that accepts a worksheet as an argument and returns the last used row number. Easy enough.  But I want to be able to use that method inside a With block that refers to a sheet.  How do I do that?  Here's what I hoped would work:

```
Private Function LastRow(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    LastRow = Sheet.cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.End(xlDown)
End Function

Private Sub UseLastRow()
    With g_PeopleSheet
        msgbox "Last used row: " & LastRow(.)
    End With
End Sub
```

I am using Excel 2016.

Comment: You could use `.Cells.Parent`

Comment: Are you aware that you can use `LastRow(g_PeopleSheet)` inside the With statement? There's nothing wrong with it or do you disagree? In the function, you have a missing `.Row` at the end. But that's quite an interesting way to get the last row. My one-liner would have been 'a mile long'.

Comment: Was about to say it's returning the value in the last cell (or a Type Mismatch if the last cell isn't a number), but @VBasic2008 has already pointed out it's missing the `.Row`.